# how to reopen a class in gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, overriding

I have same class in main application and a gem (mountable engine).
I want to reopen the class(defined in main applicaion) in the gem.


Main application has
app/models/test.rb

```
class Test
  def original_method
  end
end
```

in Gemfile

```
gem 'gem_name'
```

In the gem 
app/models/test.rb

```
class Test
  def add_method
  end
end
```

But main application raises an error that Test#original_method is not defined.
It looks like Test class is overwritten in the gem. Why not reopen?
How can I solve the problem??

**EDIT**

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `original_method' for #<Test:0x0000001997ca70>):
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/test_gem/app/controllers/tests_controller.rb:213:in `new'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:535:in `_run__422315203817736318__process_action__439125674649202736__callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__4226710667851682500__call__4227166089575601802__callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Please attach exact error.

Comment: undefined method `original_method' for #<Test:0x0000001e960618>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
Test.class_eval do
  def original_method
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I just came across it looking for an answer and found my own. Here's how I did it in a Rails app. Basically, instead of reopening the class you put the code in a `module` and include it in the original class.

```
# lib/extensions/gem_name/name_of_feature.rb

module Extensions
  module GemName
    module NameOfFeature
      def self.included(base)
        base.extend ClassMethods
        base.class_eval do
          # Things like association macros here
          # I.ex. belongs_to :foo
        end
      end

      def some_instance_method
        # Do something
      end

      module ClassMethods
        def some_class_method
          # Do something
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

# config/initializers/gem_name.rb

require "extensions/gem_name/name_of_feature"

GemClassToExtend.include Extensions::GemName::NameOfFeature
```

So now you can:

```
GemClassToExtend.some_class_method
GemClassToExtend.new.some_instance_method
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two test.rb files and only one of them is being loaded in your current environment. I recommend creating a mixin module in your application and then including it into the `Test` class defined in the gem.

```
module TestExtensions
  def original_method
  end
end

Test.include(TestExtensions)
```

Aside: I typically discourage monkey patching gem dependencies in this manner. Consider making a wrapper around `Test`.

Answer (score 1):

The exception you have attached claims about undefined method `original_method?` not `original_method`. Looks like you are trying to call a method with `?` at the end while it is not defined.

Comment: I mistyped. I defined Test#original_method and the exception says original_method is not defined.

Comment: Ok then first you should do - make sure your engine is not isolated. If it is - then it's model classes should be accessed with namespace.

In terms of code, make sure the file where you declare your mountable engine has no `isolate_namespace` statement.

Comment: I checked my engine.rb and delete isolate_namespace declaration. Then next `NoMethodError: undefined method \`add_method' for #<TEST:0x000000094ce560>`

Comment: You need to check why the class name in stack trace is UPPER_CASED now

Comment: I tested again and get NoMethodError: undefined method `add_method' for #<Test:0x000000094ce560>.

Comment: why not you use Test.class_eval do