# is there any way to modify the models of a gem in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, monkeypatching

I've come across this a couple of times, for instance when using the `acts-as-taggable-on` gem there are certain models defined in the `/lib/acts-as-taggable-on` folder such as `tag.rb`. I would like to modify these models, adding associations for instance, but I don't know how to do this once the gem is added to the app.

I tried looking around for infos on how to modify the gems but I only found somewhat confusing info about monkey patching using initializers. Is there any clear info on this, or suggestions on where to look?

Comment: Do you want to change the structure of the database tables (for example, add new columns to `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag`)? Or, add new behavior? Or both? Or? Your options depend a bit on what you're wanting to do.

Comment: I would like to change the database structure but also if possible add relations with other models @jvillian

Comment: If you want to add columns, I would suggest you look into multi table inheritance as, for instance, [here](https://www.belighted.com/blog/implementing-multiple-table-inheritance-in-rails). To add associations, you could consider single table inheritance or just reopening the class.

Comment: what do you mean with reopening the class? Also just to maybe add to my first question, the models in the gem source are present as .rb files. Are those files anywhere once the gem is loaded into the app?

Comment: For more on reopening classes, see [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+reopen+class). Of course the gem `.rb` files are somewhere. Everything is somewhere. But, if you're thinking of modifying those files, then don't do that. It's a very bad idea.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48665268/6661235) fits perfectly my situation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to add a new file reopening the class and adding methods/behavior:

```
class ActsAstaggableOn::Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  def awesome_method
    puts "I'm awesome!"
  end
end
```